# display goes off with ctrl + alt + f1

Tags: linux-mint

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> 
+<kbd>F1</kbd> (to <kbd>F7</kbd>), my display goes off. I know I do get to the tty screen because if I type my username and password, and go back to terminal and type `who`, then I can see a record of it.

I think it happened after finally getting the nvidia drivers to work without getting a black screen after booting.

Comment: The second sentence above becomes unclear where it says "goes If".

Answer (score 1):

This sort of problem crops up occasionally (not just nvidia) and sometimes has a solution: upgrading to the latest (presumably better) version.  Some people switch to the nouveau "open source" driver (not necessarily better, but different — your mileage may vary).

Further reading:

- [How to solve black screen problem after installing nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691946/how-to-solve-black-screen-problem-after-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-15-1)
- [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)
- [Black screen with nouveau on a GeForce 8600M GT, either LiveCD or fresh install](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/713864)
- [nomodeset to correct nouveau driver black screen after login](http://debianelectronics.blogspot.com/2014/05/nomodeset-to-correct-nouveau-driver.html)

Answer (score 1):

-This That occurs is the change of terminals, with this you "jump" switch to another terminal can log in as another user ... or even as ('*Super User*') "root", to return to your active terminal use the "**CTRL**+ **ALT** + **F9**" combination.